# Get lifetime sales by city in Magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento

For the first time I'm facing the gigantic Magento database. For everything Magento has more that one table: sales_X where X can take 6 values, hehe. I'm officially lost. I want to be able to obtain the following info out of Magento records but to be blunt, I don't know where to start.

This is is what I need to extract (For California state):

```
City | County | Tax Rate | Tax Dollar Amount Collected | Total City Sales Amount

Example: Santa Monica | Los Angeles | 9.5% | $95.00 | $1,000
```

If someone can help me with this I will appreciate very much. If it's possible to achieve this using admin grids, pointing in that direction works too.

Comment: What are the actual columns in the database?

Comment: I don't know. I'm brand new with Magento. In some tables I see more than 4 fields related to tax for example. I'm really lost.

Comment: SELECT * FROM sales_1 UNION SELECT * FROM sales_2 UNION SELECT * from sales_n;

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I can't fully understand you solution.

Comment: Well, it might be that the information you need is in different tables, which then you will need to use joins. Are you familiar with that concept?

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept. My issue, though, is that I don't know where to find the information in the tables. Magento's DB is really complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you need this for the billing address:

```
SELECT `city`, `region`, `tax_percent`, SUM(`tax_amount`), SUM(`grand_total`) 
FROM `sales_flat_order_address` 
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON `sales_flat_order_address`.parent_id = `sales_flat_order`.entity_id 
WHERE `address_type` = 'billing' 
GROUP BY `tax_percent`, `city`
```

If you want it based on shipping address:

```
SELECT `city`, `region`, `tax_percent`, SUM(`tax_amount`), SUM(`grand_total`) 
FROM `sales_flat_order_address` 
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON `sales_flat_order_address`.parent_id = `sales_flat_order`.entity_id 
WHERE `address_type` = 'shipping' 
GROUP BY `tax_percent`, `city`
```

Comment: You're quickly becoming my hero, hehe. Can I use that SQL syntax in my Grid or I have to convert that to Magento "languaje"?

Comment: In your _prepareCollection start with:
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');

then left join the sales/order table (can't remember the syntax for that)

then group with

$collection-> getSelect() ->group('tax_percent, city');

and

$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('tax_sum',  new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(`tax_amount`)', array());
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('grand_total_sum',  new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(`grand_total`)', array());

Comment: The invoice doesn't have that info? The idea is to get lifetime sales and I'm really confused. Should I take that info from orders or invoices?