# How to reference the right layout file in Magento

Tags: magento, layout, module, controller, admin

I'm trying to create an extension to show a custom grid in admin area. My controller is working, I can print a "Hello World" from the indexAction, but there is no way I can make it use the layout I defined. It shows a blank content area and no error. If I invalidate the layout file XML structure, no error. THat tells me that the layout especification in indexAction is being ignored. I have tried many ways to reference it but non work. all the necessary files are in place. It seems that my problem is in the path to the layout (its signaled with a comment in code: //Problem HERE!). If I use 'adminhtml/sales_invoice' it works, so it's a problem with my path. Does someone knows how exactly I can reference the layout given the structure bellow?

```
mycompany
-myextension
--Block
---adminhtml
----Container
-----Grid.php
----Container.php
--controllers
---adminhtml
----IndexController.php
--etc
```

This is my IndexController:

```
<?php
class Surpassweb_AdvancedSalesReport_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();

        //The problem is HERE!
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('dont know/what_goes_here'))
        ->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

This is my config.xml (the part related with layout)

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <myextension>
                <file>mycompany/advancedsalesreport.xml</file>
            </myextension>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('dont know/what_goes_here')
```

should be

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('advancedsalesreport/adminhtml_container')
```

where advancedsalesreport comes from this part of your config.xml

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <advancedsalesreport>
                <class>Surpassweb_AdvancedSalesReport_Block</class>
            </advancedsalesreport>
        </blocks>
</global>
```

however rather than using createBlock in the controller I prefer to define the block within the layout file in your case (mycompany/advancedsalesreport.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <yourroute_adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="advancedsalesreport/adminhtml_stock_purchaseOrder_new" name="new_purchase_order" />
        </reference>
    </yourroute_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

where yourroute matches the admin > routers part of your config.xml

Comment: Bingo! This works! Just to clarify... I used the first approach. To use the second I don't define the <global> part in the config? Is it necessary? In <block type="..." can you edit it and put something more close to my setup? Not being lazy, just cannot connect it. thanks for your help.

Comment: edited as requested, apologies had just copied it previously from a module I was working on.

Comment: No need to apologize, you've been more than helpful already. Thanks. Would you consider taking a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396229/get-lifetime-sales-by-city-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

in your controller use

```
<?php
class Surpassweb_AdvancedSalesReport_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();

        //The problem is HERE!
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('AdvancedSalesReport/adminhtml_Container_Grid'))
        ->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

end in your Grid.php

```
<?php

class class Surpassweb_AdvancedSalesReport_Block_adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setTemplate('AdvancedSalesReport/yourform.phtml');
    }
}
```

path for model:

```
-app
--design
---adminhtml
----default
-----default
------template
-------AdvancedSalesReport
--------yourform.phtml
```

Comment: In this case I still need to have a layout file?

Comment: I tried and din't work but the other answer works, so I stick with it. Thanks for your time, though, I appreciate it.